# Can I use a CR2025 battery instead of CR2032 for my AirTag?

Tags: battery, repair, find-my, airtag

I started to see that one of my AirTag batteries was getting low so I decided to change it. I already bought some CR2025 batteries already and when trying with one, it seems to work perfectly fine. Apple recommended using CR2032 (which is a bit thicker), but I was wondering if it was safe to use the thinner version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the two battery contacts inside the AirTag still make good contact with the two sides of a CR2025 battery, the only negative effect of using a CR2025 battery would probably be that it would run an AirTag for about 6.7% less time than a CR2032 battery, since the capacity of a typical CR2025 is about 170 mAh (milliamp hours), while the capacity of a typical CR2032 battery is about 200mAh.

Answer (score 1):

If the fit is tight, you can use it. The difference, other than a little longevity, Is entirely the thickness.